# Yii2 Rest API Url Rewriting (with Modules)

Tags: rest, url, url-rewriting, yii2

I have the following in my configuration:

```
 'modules' => [
            'v0' => [
                'class' => 'app\modules\v0\Module',
            ],
            'v1' => [
                'class' => 'app\modules\v1\Module',
            ],
        ],
```

And the following URL Manager entry:

```
     'urlManager' => [
                'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
                'enableStrictParsing'=>true,
                'showScriptName' => false,

                'rules' => [
                    ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => ['v0/customer','v0/object']],           
]
```

I have the following api calls for Update (PUT), View (GET), Delete (DELETE):

```
https://myapi.com/v0/objects/12345?name=warehouse
https://myapi.com/v0/objects/12345?name=product
```

I would like to be able for the user to access this using the following format: https://myapi.com/v0/objects/warehouse/12345

I have taken a look at rewrite rules but I think the module may be tricky. Can anyone shed some light on this for me please?

My web/.htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SO after a bit of fiddling - this works. I think because I am using a module there are some things that get applied in the context of the module before the rules kick in. I think the rules are relative to the module/controller.

Anyhow - this works - I used patterns (as opposed to extraPatterns) because I want to explicitly define all the rules myself.

```
   ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => ['v0/object'], 'patterns'=>[
                    'GET <name>/<id>'=>'view',
                    'PUT <name>/<id>'=>'update',
                    'DELETE <name>/<id>'=>'delete',
                    'POST <name>'=>'create',
                    'GET <name>'=>'index',
                ]],
```

Comment: Ok, nice. Havn't used 'patterns' before as I've always used the default patterns and added 'extraPatterns'. Good to know.

Comment: Yep - In this case I wanted to explicitly support only these rules. Thanks for your help Karpy

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this... (not tested)

```
'rules' => [
    [
        'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
        'controller' => 'v0/object',            
        'extraPatterns' => [
            'GET <name:[\w-]+>/<id:\d+>' => 'view',
            'PUT <name:[\w-]+>/<id:\d+>' => 'update',
            'DELETE <name:[\w-]+>/<id:\d+>' => 'delete',
        ],
    ],
],
```

Assuming you have these methods in your ObjectController:

```
public function actionView($id, $name)

public function actionUpdate($id, $name)

public function actionDelete($id, $name)
```

Be careful if you extend ObjectController from yii\rest\controller as it defines defaults for update/view/delete/index (the questions doesn't tell). If so, I would rename the methods above and use the 'only' directive to only include these methods of the controller.

Comment: I will try this - I do extend yii\rest\controller but I override actions and unset all the actions I implemented so we should be good there, I will take a look at  your patterns. Thank you

Comment: Hi Karpy, This does not seem to work - I am trying to following:
`code`['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => ['v0/object'], 'extraPatterns'=>[
                    'GET object/<name:[\w-]+>/<id:\d+>'=>'view',

                ]],

Comment: Hi, Just spotted a mistake in my code and edited my answer. Change this part... 'extraPatterns'=>[ 'GET <name:[\w-]+>/<id:\d+>'=>'view', ]] . The controller name should not be repeated after GET, since it's already set by the 'controller'-param.